# Exception Handling in Powershell 1.0

Tags: powershell, exception, ftp, powershell-1.0

I am using the following code to upload a file using PowerShell 1.0. How can I tell if the upload completed successfully or if there was an error? I need to delete the file if the upload was successful.

What I have tried:
1. the trap clause. Cant seem to get this one to work.
2. Checking the return value of $webclient.UploadFile -- this seems to always be an empty string, success or not

`$File = "D:\Dev\somefilename.zip"
$ftp = "ftp://username:password@example.com/pub/incoming/somefilename.zip"`

"ftp url: $ftp"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

"Uploading $File..."

$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $File)

Answer (score 3):

Drop the trap down into a new scope so that you trap on the exception thrown by Upload e.g.:

```
$succeeded = $true;
& {
    trap { $script:succeeded = $false; continue }
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $File)
}
if ($succeeded) { 'Yay!' } else { 'Doh!' }
```

You could also try to catch a specific exception like so:

```
trap [System.Net.WebException] { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UploadFile` method is synchronous. If it completes without throwing an exception, you have had success. You should get a trappable WebException if it fails.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx

I'll leave out details about error trapping, as it appears you are familiar with it already.

Comment: Any example of error trapping would be helpful. I have tried trap[Exception]{$failed = "true"} but keep getting errors that Powershell does not recognize trap as a cmd-let

Comment: Here's a page with some good examples. Note that they do their trapping within the function containing (pardon the pun) exceptionable code, and place the trap logic first. I hope this helps.

http://huddledmasses.org/trap-exception-in-powershell/